# Usar jquery.validate para validar dimensões da imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery.validate

Gostaria de saber como usar o [jquery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) para validar as dimensões da imagem que está sendo enviada. No meu caso, a imagem tem que ter 400px de altura e largura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer isso é necessário criar uma validação customizada, segue um exemplo:

```js
function readImage(file, element) {
var reader = new FileReader();
var image  = new Image();

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function (_file) {
    image.src = _file.target.result;
    image.onload = function() {
        $(element).data('height', this.height);
        $(element).data('width', this.width);
        $(element).data('size', ~~((file.size / 1024) / 1024));
    }
}
};

jQuery.validator.addMethod('height', function (value, element, param) {
if ($(element).data('height')) {
    return $(element).data('height') == param;
}    return this.optional(element) || true;
}, 'A altura deve ser exatamente {0}px');

jQuery.validator.addMethod('width', function (value, element, param) {
if ($(element).data('width')) {
    return $(element).data('width') == param;
}    return this.optional(element) || true;
}, 'A largura deve ser exatamente {0}px');

jQuery(function ($) {
"use strict";
$('#image').change(function () {
   var files = this.files;
    if (files && files[0]) {
        readImage(files[0], '#image');
    }
});

   $('#update_profile').validate({
    rules: {
        image: {
            required: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
        }
    },
});
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<form id="update_profile" method="post" action="">
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

[Fonte 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload)

[Fonte 2](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/image-width-and-height-validation?page=1)

Comment: Muito bom. Obrigado!