# Como faço uma consistência no form para ele aceitar somente imagens de 100x100?

Tags: php, javascript, html, imagem, crud

estou fazendo um sistema do tipo crud e tem um campo input para o usuario enviar sua foto, porém a foto tem que ser no tamanho de 100x100, existe um modo para que o form aceite somente imagens deste tamanho ou menor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904008/1244639 Essa resposta tem o que você quer.

Comment: *1)* Eu não sei se existe como burlar isso manipulando as tags da imagem. *2)* Eu recomendaria você aceitar imagens maiores e permitir que o usuário fizesse o `crop` por conta própria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como vai as coisas no CTI?

Cara da pra você fazer isso com javascript, segue um jeito aqui:
[Usar jquery.validate para validar dimensões da imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142542/usar-jquery-validate-para-validar-dimens%C3%B5es-da-imagem)

E também recomendo você fazer a validação se a imagem é das extensões certas (PNG,JPEG...etc) e também recomendo você usar a função filesize para validar se o usuário não ta enviando nenhum wallpaper e acabar com o espaço do seu servidor.